# css rules not showing up

Tags: css

I have the following css rules set for `#container nav` at this [site](http://update.techbasics.ca)

```
#container nav {
    margin-left: none;
    margin-right: none; } }
```

although when I use inspector the margins are not written, the selector is just empty no rules at all. Not sure what could be causing this. How do I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
#container nav {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

`none` is not a proper value for `margin`. Should use `0`.

Comment: so silly of me, you wouldn't believe how long this was slowing me down for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `none`. Use

```
margin-left: 0;
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

`none` is not an acceptable value for margin. Use `0` instead.